# System CPU load does not get reflected in Grafana

Tags: devops, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter, cadvisor

I have run node exporter, cAdvisor, prometheus and grafana through docker compose file.
I also imported a [dashboard with ID 395 from grafana.com](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/395-main-overview/) to monitor host and different docker containers.

I created dummy CPU load on my Ubuntu with following bash script:

```
$ for i in 1 2 3 4; do while : ; do : ; done & done
```

My system monitor looks like this:

[image]

However this CPU load doesnt get reflected on Grafana panel that came pre configured in this dashboard:

[image]

The query editor of the panel looks like this:

[image]

What I am missing here? Are queries ill formed?